# TLS 1.2 on Windows Server 2016 and .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, windows, tls1.2, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I have this error using .NET 3.5 on Windows Server 2016 when I try to use TLS 1.2:

Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The requested security protocol is not supported.

at System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_SecurityProtocol (SecurityProtocolType value)

TLS 1.2 has been released as a patch to .NET 3.5, according to the articles below. No patch for Windows Server 2016?

Note: Windows update is up to date, and I have servers with Windows Server 2008R2 and 2012 working with TLS 1.2.

Note2: I can't use .NET 4.0, i need to use .NET 3.5.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154520/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework

Comment: You need to configure some registry settings on the Server 2016 for enabling the TLS 1.2 protocol - `Client Key (DWORD Enabled = 1 and DisabledByDefault = 0)` and Server Key `(DWORD Enabled = 1 and DisabledByDefault = 0)` in the Registry path: `HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2`.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, No effects, the error continues.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the registry edit made by you, and edit the same in the question?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: do you have any update for this topic? thx

Comment: We have the same problem and found another thread on microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/459134/tls-12-with-windows-server-2016-and-net-35.html with more explanation, but it doesn't work. It works for other Windos OS but not for WS2016 Datacenter edition (on AWS).